# Como ler um arquivo de texto em Java?

Tags: java, string, arquivo

Tenho o arquivo que se chama `dados.txt` e quero colocá-lo numa `String`. Por exemplo:

```java
String texto = lerArquivo("conteudo.txt");
```

### Pergunta

Como escrever esse método `lerArquivo()`?

Answer (score 22):

A forma mais fácil de ler um arquivo em Java, depois do Java 7, é através da biblioteca NIO2. Você faz isso com uma única linha de código:

```java
String dados = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
```

É também a forma mais rápida. Consideravelmente mais rápido do que o `Scanner` e demais soluções apresentadas. A classe `Files` também possui um método para ler linha por linha guardando o resultado numa lista, e possui suporte a diferentes encodings.

Comment: Para deixar a resposta mais completa, porque não mostras como poderia ser o método `lerArquivo`? Isso deixa sua resposta mais completa, por responder exatamente o que foi pedido na pergunta. Ou, se um método `lerArquivo` não for uma boa ideia, podes também explicar o porquê. [Referência](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/491/o-que-fazer-com-respostas-que-sao-boas-mas-nao-respondem-o-que-foi-perguntado?cb=1)

Answer (score 12):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é utilizando a biblioteca padrão NIO2 (*New Input/Output 2*), disponível a partir do Java 7:

```java
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException 
{
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
}
```

Uso:

```java
String content = readFile("test.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String content = readFile("test.txt", Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Fonte: [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326440/520779) no SOEN. Note que essa solução usa uma quantidade considerável de memória, mas é simples e "segura" (i.e. não apresenta problemas com codificações multi-byte, como o UTF-8 - o que demandaria uma atenção especial, caso você optasse por uma estratégia mais eficiente, como quebrar o arquivo em *chunks*). Como você pretende carregar o arquivo inteiro em memória, estou assumindo que ele é razoavelmente pequeno.

Note também que esse método preserva quebras de linha, i.e. se seu arquivo usa o padrão Windows (`\r\n`), Unix (`\n`) ou Mac antigo (`\r`), isso será mantido igual na `String` retornada. Se quiser normalizar as quebras de linha, use algo como o [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) - tal como sugerido por @Calebe Oliveira - mas usando um [`StringWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) como saída em vez do [`System.out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) (que imprime para a tela, e não para uma `String`).

**Atualização:** como apontado por @Elias Developer em sua resposta, um outro método da classe [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) pode ser usado tanto para a conversão de *encoding* quanto pra quebra de linhas, e que dá suporte a diversas modalidades de quebra de linha, de acordo com [a documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29):

```java
List<String> linhas = readAllLines(Paths.get("conteudo.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Answer (score 12):

Apenas Listando alguns outros métodos:

**Classe `Files` no Java 11+** (recomendado)

```java
String texto = Files.readString(Path.get("dados.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

**O truque do Scanner:**

```java
String texto = new Scanner(new File("dados.txt"), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

**[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)** (útil para quem ainda não pode usar o Java 7):

```java
String texto = Files.toString(new File("dados.txt"), Charsets.UTF_8);
```

**[Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) - método 2**:

```java
String texto = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("dados.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

---

Lembrando que o Java 7 possui a classe [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) e em *containers* Java EE é boa prática usar os métodos [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) e / ou [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) para ler os recursos do *Classpath* (evitando problemas com empacotamento, etc).

Enquanto não há nada errado em instanciar arquivos através da classe `File` como fiz aqui, vale a pena mencionar que existem maneiras análogas de ler um arquivo para uma String através de `InputStream`, `Reader`, `Channel`, `URL`, `Path`, etc (o colega @mgibsonbr por exemplo utilizou técnicas de NIO 2 envolvendo a classe [Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)).

A programação para essas interfaces pode facilitar o reaproveitamento de código. Por exemplo, se você programar um método que recebe um `File` ele só funcionará com arquivos; se o mesmo método receber uma `InputStream` você pode ler conteúdo de uma infinidade de locais (arquivos, memória, rede, etc).

Eu tenho o hábito de escrever uma classe `Util` com métodos para fazer esse tipo de operação em cima de `Streams` e, conforme a necessidade, sobrecarregar esses métodos para receber outras interfaces mais comuns (no geral é trivial abrir uma `Stream` a partir de qualquer coisa em Java, enquanto o contrário nem sempre é possível) .

**Fonte:** [How to create a Java String from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/326390/664577)

Answer (score 11):

Existem diversas formas de se fazê-lo. Aí vão algumas:

### Opção 1

```java
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("dados.txt");
    try {
        String texto = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

por [@Knubo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716623/1604223).

### Opção 2

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("dados.txt"));
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Desta forma, você pode ler linha por linha.

Comment: Se você quer guardar dados, seria bom optar por um banco de dados.

Comment: É bom lembrar também que é preciso ter atenção à codificação (*encoding*) do arquivo. A primeira opção (`InputStream`) trabalha apenas com **byes**, não caracteres (embora não sei o que o `IOUtils` faz), e a segunda (`FileReader`) usa a codificação padrão do sistema.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, o [javadoc](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java.html) do `IOUtils.toString()`: "Get the contents of an InputStream as a String using the default character encoding of the platform."

Comment: Comentário que faltou. IOUtils pertence à biblioteca [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o Apache Commons IO, podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

```java
String conteudo = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("arquivo.txt"));
```

Podemos também definir o *charset* que deve ser utilizado para a leitura de duas formas.

**Método 1**

```java
String conteudo = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("arquivo.txt"), Charsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

**Método 2**

```java
String conteudo = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("arquivo.txt"), "ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso este método:

```
public List<String> readFile(String fileName){

        List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(fileName)));
            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
            String mLine;
            while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.add(mLine);
                Log.i(TAG, "          line " + mLine);
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"sucess "+fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "error " + fileName);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //log the exception
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
```

A vantagem as outras respostas é que este método retorna uma lista das linhas do texto-arquivo.