# Retorno nulo em método?

Tags: java, android

Tenho um método em que a função dele é,ler um arquivo e armazenar o valor escrito no arquivo em uma variável e retornar a variável,está aqui o método:

```
public String addItemCreative(File f){
    String line = null;
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
  return line;
}
```

O valor retornado é nulo, porque?

Comment: Coloca um `sysout` dentro do `while` e veja se é exibido.

Comment: Tens como colocar o conteúdo do arquivo na pergunta? É só clicar em [edit].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Ler um arquivo para uma String

Não precisa criar um método para isso. A forma recomendada para ler um arquivo inteiro para uma `String` é a [seguinte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1826/227):

```
String dados = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
```

Preferencialmente, especifique um *encoding* para evitar problemas com caracteres especiais:

```
String dados = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

## Problemas com algumas implementações

### Concatenando Strings

Uma das respostas oferece:

```
public static String addItemCreative(File f) {
    String line, lines = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines += line;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Isso não é bom porque cada concatenação de duas Strings gera uma terceira e a memória é consumida exponencialmente. Se o arquivo for grande, isso vai forçar o *garbage collector* a executar várias vezes, pausando a execução do programa e levando a um desempenho muito ruim.

O correto é usar `StringBuilder` em implementações locais, que é uma classe que permite concatenar Strings sem necessidade de sincronização do objeto. A resposta do @cantoni oferece um exemplo de como fazer isso.

## Quebras de linha

Se o arquivo tiver quebras de linha, você está ignorando-as ao juntar na String. Ao chamar o método `readLine` o Java não inclui as quebras.

Se quiser que o conteúdo da String seja igual ao do arquivo, você deve concatenar as quebras manualmente.

## Chamando `readLine` mais de uma vez

Na implementação da pergunta, o método `readLine` é chamado duas vezes. Se o arquivo contém uma única linha, a segunda chamada vai retornar `null`.

Se o arquivo tiver mais linhas, o resultado vai ser uma String com as linhas ímpares do arquivo.

## Tratamento de exceções

A exceção que deve ser capturada é `IOException`. Não capture exceções mais genéricas desnecessariamente. Você pode acabar encobrindo erros.

Além disso, chamar o método `getMessage` não faz nada. No mínimo vocie deve imprimir o log de erro para entender o que está acontecendo. Por exemplo:

```
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ou capture o erro e faça algo com isso

```
} catch(IOException e) {
    String erro = e.getMessage();
    mostraErro(erro);
}
```

## Faltou fechar o arquivo

Em Java é fácil esquecer que nem todo recurso alocado é liberado automaticamente.

Ao abrir um arquivo para leitura ou escrita, lembre-se de fechar o arquivo depois.

Isso pode ser feito através do método `close` de uma das implementaçnoes do `Reader` utilizadas ou automaticamente através do `try-with-resources` do Java 6. Exemplo:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
    ...
}
```

No código acima, o método `close` do `BufferedReader` será automaticamente invocado no fim do block `try`.

## Boas práticas em geral

Use variáveis no menor escopo possível. Ao invés de declarar a variável `line` no início do método, ela pode esta dentro do bloco `try` e no `catch` você retorna null diretamente. Reusar variáveis pode ser confuso.

Uma possível implementação juntando tudo que descrevi acima seria:

```
String quebra = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public String addItemCreative(File f) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(quebra);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

## Retorno opcional

Se quiser ir além e reforçar semanticamente que o método tem um retorno opcional, por exemplo no caso do arquivo não existir ou estar vazio, pode usar as novas interfaces do Java 8 como [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Essas interfaces evitam que seja necessário usar o `null` para especificar ausência de valor. Isso evita muitos `NullPointerException`s por falta de atenção, já que obriga o código cliente a verificar se existe um valor retornado pelo método.

Exemplo:

```
String quebra = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public Optional<String> addItemCreative(File f) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(quebra);
        }
        return sb.length() > 0 ? Optional.of(sb.toString()) : Optional.empty();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Agora fica fácil quem chama o método saber que ele pode não retornar algum valor.

Supondo que você queria imprimir o conteúdo. O método poderia ser usado assim:

```
Optional<String> conteudo = addItemCreative(arquivo);
if (conteudo.isPresent()) {
    imprimir(conteudo.get());
} else {
    imprimir("[arquivo vazio]");
}
```

Ainda, se preferir um formato mais funcional:

```
imprimir(addItemCreative(arquivo).orElse("[arquivo vazio]"));
```

Comment: Essa deve ser a resposta considerada correta, pois é a mais completa e contém informações muito úteis para leitura de arquivos textos com Java. Espero que o autor reavalie, pois deixar a resposta atual como a correta não é bom para o SOpt.

Comment: Vlw luiz mim ajudou mt a evitar vários erros, irei utilizar seu  exemplo.

Comment: Com respostas como essas que faz o SOpt ser uma fonte didatica de peso imenso em meio a tantos sites de tutoriais.

Comment: Mas que *loucuressante* esse tal de `Optional<?>`, gostei.

Comment: @renan Essas classes que possibilitam Programação Funcional em Java é uma das gambiarras mais legais que já inventaram. :D

Answer (score 7):

Pelo que eu entendi, a *intenção* do seu código é ler o conteúdo do arquivo inteiro, como texto, e retorná-lo, é isso mesmo? Se for, tenho três observações:

1. Comece com a string vazia, pois assim se o arquivo estiver vazio vai retornar `""`, não `null`;
2. Use uma variável *diferente* para armazenar o valor de retorno e a linha sendo lida;
3. Ao ler algo e testar por `null`, **não leia de novo**, pois se você fizer isso você estará lendo a linha *seguinte* à que foi lida, e não a mesma linha. E pior, esse nova linha pode vir `null`...

Exemplo:

```
public String addItemCreative(File f) throws IOException {
    String ret = "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
        ret = line;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

(Nota: o [exemplo do cantoni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100023/215) com `StringBuilder` é melhor que o meu, pois evita ficar criando novos objetos `String` sem necessidade)

Answer (score 4):

O fato de você estar fazendo um tratamento silencioso de exceção está te prejudicando a entender o que está acontecedo. Exceções podem ser tratadas de maneira silenciosa, mas desde que não prejudiquem execuções posteriores do código.

Retire o tratamento de exceção e veja o que está ocorrendo quando você faz:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

O seu erro acontece nessa linha. Provavelmente o arquivo passado como parâmetro pra FileReader não existe.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Um maneira de iterar sobre um arquivo texto pode ser vista abaixo:

```
public String addItemCreative(File f){
    StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

    while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
        lines.append(line);
    }

    return lines.toString();
}
```

Comment: Existe, o problema foi na atribuição pra variável line

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como saber exatamente o motivo sem você mostrar o arquivo.

Mas é bem provável que o arquivo não tenha nenhuma linha, fazendo com que o código dentro do `while` (que é a parte que dá um valor para `line`) não seja executado.

No fim de tudo é retornado `line` foi atribuída como `null` e não recebeu nenhum valor.

Também pode estar ocorrendo algum erro ao tentar abrir o arquivo e você não está vendo isso pois está silenciando a `exception`. Se você tirar esse `try-catch` verá o que está acontecendo. Pode ser o arquivo não exista, que você não tenha permissão para abri-lo, etc.

Comment: Realmente o arquivo não tem uma linha, mas ele tem caracteres.Vou tentar usando mais de um linha

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer da seguinte forma concatenando linha por linha:

```
public static String addItemCreative(File f) {
    String line, lines = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines += line;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Ou também fazer da seguinte forma com StringBuilder:

```
public String addItemCreative(File f) {

    StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return lines.toString();

}
```

Comment: Vlw, funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Uma coisa que deve ficar clara nesse código e no código da pergunta é que são feitas duas leituras de linhas por iteração. Uma leitura é feita no while e a outro é feita dentro do while. Muito provavelmente isso pode gerar problema, pois o natural é ler uma linha por iteração.

Comment: Então utilizando este trecho de código não deve dar nenhum erro:

Comment: while((line+=br.readLine()){   }

Comment: @CarlosHenrique Isso também não vai funcionar, vai entrar num loop infinito, pois `line` nunca será vazio, e ele só vai ficar acrescentando `"null"` no final da string a vida toda.

Comment: Não coloquei o != null pq isso é lógico

Comment: @CarlosHenrique, atualizei minha resposta com uma maneira de fazer a leitura do arquivo. O readLine do BufferedReader retorna a linha atual e passa para a próxima. Portanto, se você chamar ele mais de uma vez dentro do loop, então você lerá mais linhas do que deseja.

Comment: Concatenar `String`s dessa forma pode facilmente levar a picos de uso de memória e pausas para coleta das `String`s não usadas na memória. O correto é usar `StringBuilder` para concatenar o arquivo e retornar uma String no final.