# Ler arquivos .txt e os colocar em um ArrayList

Tags: java

Como fazer para ler o arquivo .txt abaixo e o transformar em um ArrayList?

```
Alicate;6;3.4

Martelo;10;4.5
```

O ArrayList no final ficaria assim: **[[Alicate, 6, 3.4],[Martelo,10;4.5],...]**

```
try{

            FileReader fr = new FileReader("ferramentas.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String str;
            while((str = br.readLine()) != null){
                out.println(str + "\n");
            } 

        }
        catch(IOException e){
        out.println("Arquivo não encontrado!");}
    }
```

Comment: Para ficar desse jeito somente utilizando uma ArrayList dentro de outra. `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();`. A depender do que você queira, talvez seja melhor outra solução.

Comment: Se cada linha é um produto, a melhor solução é criar uma classe para isso e à medida que lê os elementos do arquivo cria objetos da classe com as informações da linha respetiva.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como ler um arquivo de texto em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1823/4808)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode utilizar o método [`Files#readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:", "ferramentas.txt"); // C:\ferramentas.txt
List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(path);
```

#### [Funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@reebr/read-txt-file)

Answer (score 1):

A classe String tem o método [split(String regex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), que quebra um String em um array levando como parâmetro um caracter que se repita dentro dessa String. Esse array então vai conter todos os elementos que, na sua String original, estavam separados pelo `;`.

No seu caso, você tem `;` como um caracter repetidor. Dessa forma, você pode fazer assim para criar uma lista que contenha os elementos de um array:

```
List<String> exemplo = Arrays.asList(str.split(";"));
```

Observando o método de trás para frente, você primeiro splita a String em um array usando o ";" como caracter separador, depois converte esse array em uma lista e, finalmente, armazena essa lista numa variável chamada exemplo.

Para a sua necessidade específica, a ideia seria ter uma lista que armazenasse arrays de String. Ao ler cada linha e usando o método split, você adicionaria o retorno desse método a essa lista criada. Depois da leitura total do arquivo, basta imprimir essa lista. Seria algo assim:

```
    List<String[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();    
    try {

            FileReader fr = new FileReader("ferramentas.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String str;
            while((str = br.readLine()) != null){
                lista.add(str.split(";"))
            } 

     } catch(IOException e) {
           out.println("Arquivo não encontrado!");
     } finally {
         br.close(); 
     }

     lista.forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
```