# main(String[]) excede limite 65535 bytes

Tags: java, string

Olá.

preciso executar o código abaixo com valores que excedem os permitidos pela String do main, o que eu faço?

É uma lista de números que excede os 65535 caracteres.

na realidade o programa será usado para varios conjuntos, por isso que o "a" está entre chaves

Devido a quantidade de caracteres coloquei os dados no Drive abaixo:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vDkNdFZv4C1zGverTvkLcQVwHyCBWVtI_Rz4xCEIDRQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Nao coloque em links de dificil acesso, se náo da pra acessar aqui, coloque em sites proprios para isso como pastebin ou ideone

Comment: Você quer passar mais de 65k como argumento ao `main` ? Certamente não parece boa ideia. Melhor seria ler de um arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Como você já notou, o Java não permite métodos tão longos:

```
package ordenar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class Exercicio{
      public static void main(String [] args){

        double a [] = { <um array grotescamente gigante> };

        ArrayList<Double> valores = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> par = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> impar = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int par1 =0;
        int impar1 = 0;


        for(int cont = 0; cont<a.length; cont++) {
           valores.add(cont, a[cont]);
       }     

       Collections.sort(valores);

       for(double cont = 0; cont<valores.size(); cont++) {

           double valor = valores.get((int) cont);

           if(valor%2==0) {
               par.add(valor);
               par1++;               
           }else {
               impar.add(valor);
               impar1++;
           }
       }

       System.out.println("impares "+impar1);
       System.out.println("pares " + par1);    
       System.out.println("vetor impar ");

       for (int i = 0; i < impar.size(); i++) { 
           double valor = impar.get(i);
             System.out.print(", " + valor);
        }
       System.out.println(" ");
       System.out.println("vetor par ");

       for (int i = 0; i < par.size(); i++) { 
           double valor = par.get(i);
             System.out.print(", " + valor);
        }       

    }
}
```

Esse array enorme claramente não deveria estar declarado dentro do programa. Dados devem ficar salvos em arquivos no HD, quando um programa precisar deles terá que ler os arquivos que contêm os dados.

Ou seja, crie um arquivo qualquer com esses números (por exemplo, `numeros.txt`) e faça o seu programa Java abrir o arquivo e ler os números de lá.

[Como ler um arquivo de texto em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1823/como-ler-um-arquivo-de-texto-em-java)