# Problemas com grafos em Java

Tags: java, grafo

Estou fazendo uma questão do URI e na entrada eles pedem assim.

> Entrada: A entrada termina em EOF. Para cada caso de teste, a primeira linha contém dois inteiros positivos C e P que representam respectivamente a quantidade de cidades (2 <= C <= 50) e a quantidade de pontes (1 <= P <= 1250). Seguem-se P linhas onde cada linha contém dois inteiros positivos X e Y (indexados a partir do 1) indicando que há uma ponte interligando as cidades X e Y.

Como seria esse EOF, minha duvida é somente essa, não busco resposta da questão? OBS: Estou fazendo em java.

Comment: EOF é *end of file*, indica o final do arquivo: https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOF - mas se vc ler o arquivo com a biblioteca padrão do Java, não precisa se preocupar com ele, basta ir lendo o arquivo até  ele acabar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1823/112052

Comment: então vou ter que criar um arquivo para questão? ou da pra fazer isso dentro de um while?

Comment: Não uso o uri e não sei como ele aceita as entradas (se é vc quem cria o arquivo ou se ele já tem alguns casos prontos e vc só lê). Sugiro ver no próprio site como deve ser feito

Comment: O normal será utilizar um `while` com `try catch` para a leitura de cada uma das P linhas, fazendo `break` no `catch`.

Comment: crio duas variaveis para ler X e Y das P linhas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O EOF significa fim do arquivo. Como isso daí é usado num contexto onde você lê da entrada padrão, isso significa o fim do `System.in`.

Primeiro, vamos bolar uma classe que representa uma aresta:

```
public final class Aresta {
    private final int origem;
    private final int destino;

    public Aresta(int origem, int destino) {
        this.origem = origem;
        this.destino = destino;
    }

    public static Aresta parse(String s) {
        String[] array = s.split(" ");
        return new Aresta(
            Integer.parseInt(array[0].trim()),
            Integer.parseInt(array[1].trim()));
    }

    public int getOrigem() {
        return origem;
    }

    public int getDestino() {
        return destino;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return origem + "->" + destino;
    }
}
```

Você pode ler todas as linhas da entrada assim (Java 10+):

```
    public static Stream<String> linhas(Scanner s) {
        Supplier<Optional<String>> sup = () -> {
            try {
                return Optional.of(s.nextLine());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        };
        return Stream.generate(sup).takeWhile(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get);
    }
```

Esse método funciona ao criar um [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) com linhas obtidas por meio do [método `nextLine()` da classe `Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).

Entretanto, o método `nextLine()` lança um `NoSuchElementException` quando a entrada tiver acabado, e é por isso que essa exceção é capturada e o retorno colocado dentro de um [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Com o [método `takeWhile(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)), nós podemos aceitar os elementos do `Stream` até que o `Optional` vazio apareça, desconsiderando os resultados a partir desse ponto. Vez que após isso, todos os elementos `Optional` não serão vazios, usamos o `.map(Optional::get)` para desempacotar o elemento contido no `Optional`. O resultado é um `Stream<String>` contendo o conteúdo das linhas lidas.

E então, você pode obter um `Stream<Aresta>` assim:

```
    public static Stream<Aresta> arestas(Scanner s) {
        return linhas(s).map(Aresta::parse);
    }
```

Ainda é preciso representar o seu problema como um todo, incluindo a linha com os números C e P. Podemos criar uma classe para isso também:

```
public final class Problema {
    private final int numeroCidades;

    private final List<Aresta> arestas;

    public Problema(int numeroCidades, List<Aresta> arestas) {
        this.numeroCidades = numeroCidades;
        this.arestas = arestas;
    }

    public static Problema parse(Scanner s) {
        String primeiraLinha = s.nextLine();
        String[] partes = primeiraLinha.split(" ");
        int c = Integer.parseInt(partes[0].trim());
        List<Aresta> arestas = LerLinhas.arestas(s).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new Problema(c, arestas);
    }

    public int getNumeroCidades() {
        return numeroCidades;
    }

    public List<Aresta> getArestas() {
        return arestas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{c=" + numeroCidades + ", p=" + arestas.size() + ", arestas=" + arestas + "}";
    }
}
```

Para testar isso:

```
public class LerLinhas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Problema p = Problema.parse(s);
        System.out.println(p);
    }

    public static Stream<Aresta> arestas(Scanner s) {
        return linhas(s).map(Aresta::parse);
    }

    public static Stream<String> linhas(Scanner s) {
        Supplier<Optional<String>> sup = () -> {
            try {
                return Optional.of(s.nextLine());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        };
        return Stream.generate(sup).takeWhile(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get);
    }
}
```

Testando com essa entrada:

```
5 4
2 3
1 4
2 2
4 3
```

Eis a saída:

```
{c=5, p=4, arestas=[2->3, 1->4, 2->2, 4->3]}
```

Assim sendo, com isso você já consegue uma instância de `Problema` pronta para você trabalhar. Dessa forma, você pode focar nas partes mais interessantes do problema sem se preocupar com a parte de ler e interpretar a entrada dada. Note que você não precisa se preocupar com os casos onde as entradas são mal-formadas, porque o URI nunca executa o programa enviado dessa forma.

Note que nem estou me dando ao trabalho de ler o valor de P aqui. O valor dele pode ser deduzido diretamente a partir do número de linhas lidas.

Comment: eu entendi a classe Aresta, mas não entendi as outras duas

Comment: @ArmandoDeCabro Resposta editada. Me diga se ficou melhor.

Comment: ficou melhor sim, só uma duvida agora. O que é faz "Supplier".

Comment: @ArmandoDeCabro É uma interface funcional para fornecer um objeto sem utilizar nenhum parâmetro para isso. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html

Comment: muito obrigado.